# Русский язык — сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов, этимологов(,) и энтузиастов русского языка. Полностью бесплатно, не требует регистрации

Tags: пунктуация

Печально, что информация о сайте содержит грубейшую пунктуационную ошибку. Вопрос: на сайте есть люди, знающие элементарные правила?

Comment: Дело  - в "лишней" запятой и в нехватке точки? Тогда ошибок больше?

Comment: Вот вторая часть не очень лепится. Всё в среднем роде, если не ошибаюсь: Полностью бесплатно, не требует регистрации. Это о сайте или о языке? Или о том, что, предположительно, есть Пользование или Участие? Полностью бесплатно, к тому же, нисколько не доходчивее, чем просто Бесплатно. Отличий в сумме прописью не видно. Вообще фраза лишняя: приглашения регистрироваться не видно, - ну и как-то странно говорить об этом.

Comment: Вам надо на мете этот вопрос задать. Да, это ошибка, но ошибка локализации, текст написан не конечным пользователем, а программистов скорее всего

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим на этот заголовок более позитивно. Авторы проявили новаторский подход, применив в русском знаменитую "оксфордскую запятую", предложенную когда-то американским издательством Oxford University Press. Она обозначает последний элемент перечисления, присоединяемый через "и", позволяя устранить неоднозначности, связанные (в данном случае) с наличием второго союза "и" (сайт вопросов и ответов, этимологов и энтузиастов), и этим ускоряя правильное понимание при прочтении.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Серийная_запятая

Comment: Это что-то вроде: "Они отправились в Орегон с Бетти, горничной, и  кухаркой". Забавно!

Answer (score 0):

В русском языке все правила элементарные, ничего сложного.

А это авторская пунктуация, союз И имеет присоединительное значение. Как у Пушкина: "Она вслух читала романы, и была виновата во всех ошибках автора". Если Вы в этом сомневаетесь, то можете доказать на форуме невозможность такого решения, и тогда текст поправят.

А вообще на сайте в первую очередь ценятся вежливые люди, задающие вежливые вопросы.

Comment: К сожалению, такая интерпретация постановки запятых при двух рядах однородных членах мне совершенно непонятна. В задании ЕГЭ этого года целое задание (15) посвящено умению видеть  эти несколько рядов. И мне, как эксперту сайта РЕШУ ЕГЭ, очень не хотелось бы, чтобы дети, сдавая экзамен, пользовались правилами википедии, а не учебниками русского языка. 
Пушкин, несомненно, имел право на авторские знаки. Но какое это имеет отношение к простейшему ряду однородных членов? Нет здесь никакого присоединительного значения.

Comment: Татьяна, это просто шутка, передача информации в закодированном виде.  Кроме всего прочего (о вежливости и т.д.), я хотела сказать, что любое утверждение, даже самое очевидное, всё-таки относительно, а не абсолютно. Эта та мысль, которая тоже может быть полезна детям, ведь не ЕГЭ одним  жив человек. Школа должна воспитывать думающих людей, а не только умеющих отвечать на вопросы. Вот вам кажется, что присоединительного значения здесь нет и быть не может, но это нужно доказать, сославшись на грамматику и орфографические правила.

Comment: Доказывать  очевидное я не буду, простите...Если в правилах сайта доказывать подобное,то я явно здесь лишняя.
Ваше сообщение об "умеющих думать" мне понятна. Но запутывать детей я не позволю. С уважением, вежливо-вежливо, прощайте:)
И не приведи....если кто-то из моих детей сошлётся на Ваше закодированное " а это авторская пунктуация".

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь , Татьяна, просто не проверили текст, оформление новое.  И разумеется, там нет присоединительного значения.   Вот только я теперь сама думаю: а можно ли  это вообще доказать?

Comment: И если серьезно, то это ЛУЧШИЙ РОССИЙСКИЙ ФОРУМ ПО РУССКОМУ ЯЗЫКУ.  Грамотные, обоснованные, развернутые    и практически незамедлительные ответы гарантируются.  Если ошибается один отвечающий, то его сразу поправляют другие. Где вы еще такое найдете?